# new line in javascript text variable

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer

I have this text here:

```
var text1 = '<p>Hey ' + rows[i].NAME + ', \n\nFrom our team here at Indera Technologies ...
```

I send it like this through `html` parameter in nodemailer transporter:

```
 var text1 = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head><body><p>Hey ' + rows[i].NAME + ', \n\nFrom our team here at Pier Solutions, we wanted to let you know that we have done a little re-branding. We have changed our name to... drum roll please! \n\nIndera Technologies!</p>'
                    
var text2 = '</body></html>'
                    
// send mail with defined transport object
                    let sendBatch = await transporter.sendMail({
                        from: "solutionspier@gmail.com", // sender address
                        to: rows[i].EMAIL,
                        // bcc: emails, // list of receivers
                        subject: "It's Official, we've rebranded!", // Subject line
                        html: text1 + req.body.htmlContent + text2
                    });
```

then when I send the email, it actually shows up in the email like this:

```
Hey Gianluca From our team here at Indera Technologies
```

it does all one line instead of new line.

how do I fix this?

Comment: If you're sending HTML email, newlines are not significant; they're basically the same as spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is supposed to be part of HTML, use the `<br>` tag instead of `\n`.
Or better yet, put the lower text in a separate `<p>` tag

Also, you might want to learn about [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), it's going to make writing strings like that much easier

Comment: nice answer, I appreciate it. Totally forgot that I was writing HTML inside the js variable, it slipped my mind. Thank you!